# What is making the Sub stop at row 12135 when "Lastrow" of data is row 19195?

Tags: vba, excel

The Sub written below is designed to open a workbook and copy the sheets into a template, then close the workbook leaving the template open.  It works, but there is data until row 19195 but only 12135 rows of data get copied.  What is my problem in the Sub?

```
 Sub CopySheetsl()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
Dim CopySht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("L:\ABC\test\macro\test.xlsx")
Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro.xlsm")

LastRow = range("A:A").Find("", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1", "N1" & LastRow) = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1", "N1" & LastRow).Value
wb1.Sheets("Sheet2").range("C1", "AN1" & LastRow) = wb.Sheets("Sheet2").range("A1", "AL1" & LastRow).Value

 wb.Close


 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `LastRow`? If it's 12135, then the issue is in the first part (which is what I suspect...one of the values in `range("A:A").Find("", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` is `""`). OTH, if `LastRow` is 19195, then the issue is with setting one range = to the other.

Comment: Apart `LastRow` not being what you expect, you are copying until cell `"N1" & LastRow` so I suspect that `LastRow` is equal to 2135.

Comment: The Lastrow value = range("A:A").Find("", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Comment: The data in Sheet 1 continues until row 19195 but only until row 12135 is imported as expected.  I have tried updated the Sub below with ws, but that has not worked either.

Comment: Set ws = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1") : subscript out of range

Comment: Sub CopySheetsl()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim CopySht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("L:\QC\CGI Bill Working Folder\macro\CGI Premium Billing Report.xlsx")
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb1.Sheets("Detail")
    
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     
    wb1.Sheets("Detail").range("C1", "AN1" & LastRow) = wb.Sheets("Detail_2").range("A1", "AL1" & LastRow).Value
        
    wb.Close
       
    
End Sub

Comment: Updated the above Sub but still same error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't finding the last row, it's finding an empty cell.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet : Set ws = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' last populated row in column A
```

You'll also need to recalculate it for Sheet2 unless you can be absolutely sure that both sheets have the same number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

From Ron De Bruin's site

```
    Public Function fndLast(choice As Long, rng As Range)
    'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
    ' 1 = last row
    ' 2 = last column
    ' 3 = last cell
        Dim lrw As Long
        Dim lcol As Long

        Select Case choice

        Case 1:
            On Error Resume Next
            fndLast = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
            On Error GoTo 0

        Case 2:
            On Error Resume Next
            fndLast = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
            On Error GoTo 0

        Case 3:
            On Error Resume Next
            lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                           After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                           SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                           MatchCase:=False).Row
            On Error GoTo 0

            On Error Resume Next
            lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
            On Error GoTo 0

            On Error Resume Next
            fndLast = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                fndLast = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
                Err.Clear
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

        End Select
    End Function
```